# CakePHP 1.2: Is it possible to exempt a specific controller action to its beforeFilter method?

Tags: cakephp

I am aware that I'm using an ancient version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I.E to exclude login action, write in beforefilter:

```
   if ($this->action == 'login')
    {
        // execute beforeFilter logic
    }
```

Comment: That equals should be a double on `==`

Answer (score 0):

Calling beforeFilter() works the same way in any version. What do you want to achieve?
Do you have some code in AppController you don't wan't to run?

Just implement an empty beforeFilter() wihtout calling parent::beforeFilter(), or do call it but set a flag to false to avoid running the delicate code in question.

Comment: I have a specific action on a controller where I dont want to run beforeFilter() code

Comment: In that case that action belongs to a separate controller! You can share logic between the two controllers in a common superclass.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, yes i really have a weird controller design